# How to dynamically display a list of fields on asp.net mvc page and pass input value back to back end?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario which requires the admin user to identify a number of parameters at the back end and let end user to input value for these parameters, sending back.

I am wondering is there any solution to this kind of scenario? My guess, java script would be required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a HTML Form. A form will be rendered to the user, and when the user submits the form, the entered information will be sent back to the server.

[This page](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1078491/creating-forms-in-asp-net-mvc) is a decent tutorial on how to make a HTML form using ASP.NET MVC.

You have to create a model (class) with the properties you want the user to submit.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Int32 RandomNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you will create two MVC actions. One, for requesting the form page, which will return a `ViewResult` with an empty model. The other will be the submit action, and will require a parameter with the model. This will be sent via the user's submission of the form:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public void Create()
    {
        return this.View("~/Views/FooController/Create.cshtml", new MyModel() );
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public void Create(MyModel model)
    {
        //Do something with model information, such as save to database
    }
}
```

The `ViewResult` will need to return a CSHTML page that creates a form for this model.

```
@model MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Foo", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.RandomNumber )
}
```

Comment: Thank you James, I will have a look and go through the tutorial.